# Cannot perform a CPI call using anchor

Tags: anchor, rust, program, cpi, cargo

I tried to make a CPI call from puppret_master to puppet program exactly like the anchor document and i did everything right but "program" AND "cpi" keywords are still unkown for my puppet_master program ! what should i do ?!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few areas to investigate based on the information that you've shared:

### Anchor Version

You want to make sure that both `puppet` and `puppet_master` are using the same Anchor version ("0.28.0") to ensure compatibility

### Cargo.toml

You've set `cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]` in your `puppet_master`'s `Cargo.toml`. You want to make sure that `puppet` also contains this feature definition. When the `cpi` feature is dependent on the `no-entrypoint` feature, this configuration is needed for CPIs to function correctly as they would be following the same feature constraints. A consistent feature flag ensures that the calling and called contracts have predictable behavior. Without more context, it's hard to know whether there's complete consistency among all your features

Setting `no-idl = []` could *potentially* be an issue if, for some reason, the `puppet_master` program needs to dynamically understand or parse the IDL of `puppet`. The `no-idl` feature would be an obstacle for this as IDL describes how to call functions in another contract. I note that this is a potential issue as you're already using the source code to include `puppet` as a dependency. Nonetheless, it is something to consider

### Imports

Ensure that your imports for `puppet::cpi` are done correctly

### Cache, Toolchain, Refreshing

You could try invalidating your, what looks like to be, VSCode's cache and running `rustup update`. I'd also recommend reloading the developer window by opening the command palette (Ctrl + Shift + P) and executing the command `>Reload Window`.

After checking and updating everything, try rebuilding both the `puppet` and `puppet_master` projects.

Hopefully this was helpful! Let me know if need any more help!